# How to extend Vue component with default values for props and slots?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `bootstrap-vue` in my application, and I have a lot of tables, which all have the same boilerplate code. Here's an example of what that boilerplate might look like:

```html
<b-table
  :items="someItemList"
  :busy="someItemList === null"
  :empty-text="$t('notFound')"
  :empty-filtered-text="$t('notFound')"
  no-sort-reset
  show-empty
  striped
  hover
>
  <div slot="table-busy" class="text-center my-3">
    <b-spinner class="align-middle"/>
  </div>
</b-table>
```

I would of course like to factor out this boilerplate into some sort of common module, like a custom component, so that my starting point for a new table would look something more like this:

```html
<my-awesome-table :items="someItemList">
</my-awesome-table>
```

Ultimately, I would like `my-awesome-table` to act just like a normal `b-table`, but with all of this boilerplate already set, and where I can still set extra props and slots as needed.

However, I can't figure out a way to make this work. I've tried:

- making a wrapper component, but then I struggle to expose all of the functionality of the underlying `b-table`
- extending the `b-table` component, but then I struggle to set the prop and slot values as I've set them in my boilerplate template

How can I create a custom component which allows me to set default values for props and slots?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In case you prefer templates, you could create a wrapper component like this:

1. Assign [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/api/#v-bind) to [`$attrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/api/#vm-attrs) on `b-table`, which binds any attributes from the parent:

```html
<b-table v-bind="$attrs" ...>
```

2. Assign [`v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/api/#v-on) to [`$listeners`](https://v2.vuejs.org/api/#vm-listeners) on `b-table`, which attaches any event listeners from the parent

```html
<b-table v-on="$listeners" ...>
```

3. Pass any [`$scopedSlots`](https://v2.vuejs.org/api/#vm-scopedSlots) to `b-table`:

```html
<b-table ...>                   
  <template v-for="(_, slot) of $scopedSlots" v-slot:[slot]="scope">
    <slot :key="slot" :name="slot" v-bind="scope" />
  </template>
</b-table>
```

The result should look similar to this:

```html
<template>
  <b-table
    your-prop-a
    your-prop-b
    your-prop-c
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
  >                               
    <template v-for="(_, slot) of $scopedSlots" v-slot:[slot]="scope">
      <slot :key="slot" :name="slot" v-bind="scope" />
    </template>
  </b-table>
</template>
```

[image: Edit Wrapper for b-table]

*In Vue 3, `$scopedSlots` is replaced with [`$slots`](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#slots), so that should be used instead in the examples above when migrating to Vue 3.*

Comment: I tried this with the vue2.7 compat build, <script setup> syntax, Vuetify and typescript. But sadly type validation fails for this generic-table approach. If anyone has type-validating solution I'd be flattered.

Answer (score 5):

This situation calls for a functional component. Untested, but try something like this:

**my-awesome-table.vue**

```js
export default {
  functional: true,

  render(h, ctx) {
    // Get data from the parent component
    const {
      someItemList,
      $t,
    } = ctx.parent

    return h('b-table', {
      // Pass on the full data object
      ...ctx.data,

      // Extend the props
      props: {
        items: someItemList,
        busy: someItemList === null,
        emptyText: $t('notFound'),
        emptyFilteredText: $t('notFound'),
        noSortReset: true,
        showEmpty: true,
        striped: true,
        hover: true,

        // Override the above default prop values with any props provided
        ...ctx.props,
      },
    }, [
      // Provide a default rendering for the table-busy slot
      // if one is not provided
      !ctx.slots()['table-busy'] && h('div', {
        slot: 'table-busy',
        staticClass: 'text-center my-3',
      }, [
        h('b-spinner', { staticClass: 'align-middle' })
      ],

      // Append any additional children
      ...(ctx.children || [])
    ])
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```vue
<my-awesome-table
  :items="otherList"
  :busy="isBusy"
>
</my-awesome-table>

<my-awesome-table>
  <div slot="table-busy">My custom busy slot</div>
  <div slot="something-else">Some other slot</div>
</my-awesome-table>
```

Keep in mind that the default prop values that `<my-awesome-table>` uses is strongly dependent on the parent component, but it's up to you how tightly-coupled you want it to be.

A disadvantage of this approach is you need to write the render function by hand. The Vue template compiler does have *very limited* support for functional components, but every time I have attempted to compose a functional component that way I have regretted it (the template can get messy with things that can be expressed in code with ease).